# Do single speed/fixed bicycles come with machined rims?

Tags: wheels

I recently purchased a Masi Fixie Riser with a flip/flop hub (gearing on both sides) and brakes, but the rims aren't machined. Is this common on $700+ single speeds?

Comment: This is why I recommend buying a bike at a local bike store, after you have seen and test-ridden the bike. By doing this you are able to get much more information than what you can get on the spec sheets.

Comment: Related question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16757/does-having-machined-brake-surface-on-rims-matter

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the fixie.

A lot of them don't because brakes are not cool among the fixie riding population (since they primarily want deep V rims to look nice and resistance braking).

As for not having machined rims, depending on what the rim is coated with it can be OK -- if its powdercoated/painted for example, it will be too slippery to brake, but annodized surfaces can be used for braking just fine. The rims on the Masi should be annodized so you should be good for braking.

Comment: I've used annodized rims from velocity with no issues on my bike polo bike which had a lot of quick stopping usage. Eventually the annodization wore off slightly, which isn't the most attractive thing, but it doesn't seem to affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

Is this common? Assuming your brakes are rim brakes: no, it's not common.

It's also something that's known to happen. But it's a pretty bonehead spec, IMO.